# How to call a on-onpremise BAPI in SAP Cloud SDK Java

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to call a BAPI in SAP Cloud SDK Java, not sure whats wrong with below code. Please help me here

```
final Destination destination =
        DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyErpSystem").asRfc()
        .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
final BapiRequestResult result = new BapiRequest("BAPI_COSTCENTER_GETLIST1")
                .withExporting("CONTROLLINGAREA", "BAPI0012_GEN-CO_AREA", "A000")
                .withTable("COSTCENTERLIST", "BAPI0012_CCLIST").end().withTableAsReturn("BAPIRET2")
                .execute(destination);
```

it shows syntax error at destination creation.

Comment: Hi Prakash, welcome to stack overflow. Please always include the exact, full error message and stack trace. Also please point out what SDK version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code seems to be that you try to decorate an `RfcDestination` as `DefaultErpHttpDestination`. [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Function_Call) and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) are distinct protocols, so this decoration doesn't quite make sense and is not needed. The `RfcDestination` you get via `asRfc()` should suffice.

Check out [this guide](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/bapi-and-rfc/bapi-and-rfc-overview) that explains in detail how to use the Cloud SDK to perform BAPI calls.

Comment: If i change the Destination type as Rfc, now the execute method call with destination is failing.

The method execute(Destination) in the type BapiRequest is not applicable for the arguments (RfcDestination)Java(67108979)

Comment: As I commented above please include the full error message and stack trace as well as the SDK version. Also update your question to reflect your updated code. Without that I can only point to the guide I already linked above.